# DataGridView DataSource contents duplicated

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, datasource

If I go to select a new XML file and attach it as a **datasource** to the **DataGridView** it doesn't replace the grid contents but appends to it:

```
private void buttonSelectXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlgFile = new OpenFileDialog();

    dlgFile.Title = "Select XML file";
    dlgFile.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
    dlgFile.FilterIndex = 0;
    dlgFile.Multiselect = false;
    dlgFile.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBoxXML.Text);
    dlgFile.FileName = textBoxXML.Text;

    if (dlgFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.XMLPath = dlgFile.FileName;
        textBoxXML.Text = dlgFile.FileName;

        dataSet.ReadXml(textBoxXML.Text);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

What is the right way to **replace** the current grid content with the new XML datasource rather than **append**?

Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET or Winform?

Comment: Oops - I have now added the tag winform.

Comment: `dataSet.Tables.Clear();`

Comment: @LarsTech That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way it shouldn't be the case and your grid data should get refreshed since you are rebinding it. As an alternative, try setting the datasource to null like

```
    dataSet.ReadXml(textBoxXML.Text);
    dataGridView.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not seem to resolve it. In my specific case the original datasource and the newly selected datasource are actually the same file. Does this matter?

Comment: No shouldn't be but looks like your dataset is a global object. Consider using a separate instance on every call of event handler (OR) clear your dataset before re-filling it.

Comment: Ah I assumed I needed a global dataset. Was that wrong? Is it just a temporary go between the xml and data grid?

Comment: Yes, I had to clear the dataset as per @LarsTech comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call

```
dataGridView.DataBind()
```